# Ubuntu 20.04 syslog

Tags: 20.04, syslog

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and use it for python development.

There are a few crontab jobs that run very early in the AM, however, noticed this morning they did not run as expected - but I cannot locate the /etc/log/*log files? Did it move in 20.04?

Appreciate any help and direction!

Comment: Do you mean `/var/log/syslog`  or `/var/log/cron.log`?

Comment: I was referring to syslog, but neither exist. Do I need to do anything to enable?

Comment: Please, [edit] your original question and add the output of `ls -l /var/log/*log` command. If your user is not allowed to read the `/var/log/syslog` file, you may need to use `sudo` to access it.

Comment: Read `man journalctl` and `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u cron` will show hints.